# 2 view controllers in 1

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have a container view controller and I want to load 2 view controllers in it in this way:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{  
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(320, 480);
    CGSize sizeExpand = CGSizeMake(640, 480); // size of view in popover
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"TabelStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    UIViewController *yourModalVC =[storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    yourModalVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    [self presentModalViewController:yourModalVC animated:YES];
    yourModalVC.contentSizeForViewInPopover = size;
    yourModalVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(00, 00, 320, 480);

    CGSize size2 = CGSizeMake(320, 480);
    CGSize sizeExpand2 = CGSizeMake(640, 480); // size of view in popover
    UIStoryboard *storyboard2 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"DetailsGroup" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    UIViewController *yourModalVC2 =[storyboard2 instantiateInitialViewController];
    yourModalVC2.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    [self presentModalViewController:yourModalVC2 animated:YES];
    yourModalVC2.contentSizeForViewInPopover = size2;
    yourModalVC2.view.frame = CGRectMake(320, 00, 320, 480);
}
```

But only the first one of the 2 loads. If I swap the two parts of the code, it's always the first one thar loads, so the problem is not in the code. Can I actually load two view controllers?

Comment: what does "loads" means? Did you breakpoint your code and checked that yourModalVC2 was nil?

Comment: Why you want to do stuff like that?

Comment: because I need to have a UIPopover, which can expand to schow another UIViewController